# What is the interval of Gini Index?

Tags: data-mining, econometrics, regression-coefficients, gini

Suppose we have 2 classes.

```
C1: 0
C2: 6
```

The Gini index is: $1−(0÷6)^2−(6÷6)^2 = 0$

```
C1: 3
C2: 3
```

The Gini Index is: $1−(3÷6)^2−(3÷6)^2 = 0.5$

So am I right, when I say, the Gini Index lays in the Interval of $0$ and $0.5$?
I can't think of any other examples, where it gets higher than $0.5$.

**Edit**:
Except, when there are more than 2 classes. It that even possible?

Comment: It's in the interval [0,1] unless you allow for negative income/wealth/etc.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient

Comment: `In finite populations or samples, the Gini index has an upper bound of 1-1/n`, page 869 in *Measures of Inequality*, American Sociological Review (Allison, 1978). [PDF](http://web.stanford.edu/group/scspi/_media/pdf/Reference%20Media/Allison_1978_Measurement.pdf).